# Bash script that move files from one directory with lots of files to a month folder

Tags: bash, date, directory, mv, file-structure

I have a directory with thousands of files.
They have a specific creation date.
Now I want to archive these files on specific times to a specific directory.

Example:

Files created on:

```
May 15 testmay.txt
Jun 10 testjun.txt
Jul 01 testjul.txt
```

They should come in those directory's

```
/2013-05/testmay.txt
/2013-06/testjun.txt
/2013-06/testjul.txt
```

I already have this to rsync the files from a remote server to a temp month directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

GAMESERVER=game01
IP=172.1.1.1

JAAR=`date --date='' +%Y`
MAAND=`date --date='' +%m`
DAG=`date --date=''  +%d`
LOGDIR=/opt/archief/$GAMESERVER

if [ ! -e $LOGDIR/$JAAR-$MAAND ]; then
        mkdir $LOGDIR/$JAAR-$MAAND/tmp
        chmod -R 770 $LOGDIR/$JAAR-$MAAND/tmp
fi

rsync -prlt --remove-source-files -e ssh root@$IP:/opt/logs/sessions/ $LOGDIR/$JAAR-$MAAND/tmp

chmod -R 770 $LOGDIR/ -R
```

How can I complete this script?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you want to happen next?  Just explain in words, step by step what you want to happen.

Comment: As you see in the script I catch lots of files to a tmp directory, now that tmp directory contains thousands of files.

I want those files now sorted out:
- File created in a specific month should be moved to a directory created for that month.

Comment: It looks like that is already happening... isn't `$LOGDIR/$JAAR-$MAAND/` a directory for a specific month and year?

Comment: Yes, but where I get the files, /opt/logs/sessions/, there are lots of files from different months. So it will copy them but not sort them according to the creation date.

Comment: How will you determine the creation date?  Do you search within the file, or will you do it by timestamp?  Also, will you be creating even more directories under $LOGDIR/$JAAR-$MAAND/ that are dates?  I'm confused why you are copying all of the files into a directory named after a single date, instead of copying them into something like $LOGDIR/tmp.

Answer (score 5):

I've just had need to do something similar and have come up with what I think is a pretty neat way to do it. I have >1 million files in one directory that I need to archive off based on their mtime. I'm using `zip` to archive the files here because I want them compressed but also easily accessible from Windows systems, but you could easily replace it with just a simple `mv` or whatever suits.

```
SRC="/path/to/src"  # Where the originals are found
DST="/path/to/dst"  # Where to put the .zip file archives

FIND="find $SRC -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name \*.tmp -o -name \*.log \)" # Base find command

BOUND_LOWER=$( date -d "-3 years" +%s ) # 3 years ago (because we need somewhere to start)
BOUND_UPPER=$( date -d "-1 years" +%s ) # 1 year ago (because we need to keep recent files where they are)

# Round down the BOUND_LOWER to 1st of that month at midnight to get 1st RANGE_START
RANGE_START=$( date -d $( date -d @$BOUND_LOWER +%Y-%m )-01 +%s )

# Loop over each month finding & zipping files until we hit BOUND_UPPER
while [ $RANGE_START -lt $BOUND_UPPER ]; do
    ARCHIVE_NAME=$( date -d @$RANGE_START +%Y-%m )
    echo "Searching for files from $ARCHIVE_NAME"
    RANGE_END=$( date -d "$( date -d @$RANGE_START ) +1 month" +%s )
    eval "$FIND -newermt @$RANGE_START \! -newermt @$RANGE_END -print0" |
        xargs -r0 zip -Tjm $DST/$ARCHIVE_NAME -@
    echo
    RANGE_START=$RANGE_END
done
```

For each file in `$SRC` that matches the `$FIND` conditions and is within `$BOUND_*` variable time range (to the nearest month), this will archive it to the appropriate `$DST/YYYY-MM.zip` file based on its mtime.

If you're using a version of `find` older than 4.3.3, see [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html) for examples of how to use `-newer` instead of `-newermt`, which you will just need to do inside the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
DEBUG=echo
cd ${directory_with_files}
for file in * ; do 
    dest=$(stat -c %y "$file" | head -c 7) 
    mkdir -p $dest
    ${DEBUG} mv -v "$file" $dest/$(echo "$file" | sed -e 's/.* \(.*\)/\1/')
done
```

DISCLAIMER: test this in a safe copy of your files. I won't be responsible for any lost of data ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
for file
do  dir=/`date +%Y-%m -r$file`
    mkdir -p $dir && mv $file $dir
done
```

into a script file named, let's say, `archive`, you can execute for example

```
archive *
```

to move all files to the desired directories. In case this produces a *line too long* error, execute

```
/bin/ls | xargs archive
```

instead. (If you want to be cautious, you can use the `mv -i` option.)